# My bootstrap container is not getting the full width. How to solve this problem?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want all the images to get the full width. But I am getting some padding in right and left. How can I solve this problem? Here is the image of my page:[image]

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      
        <div class="col"><a href="about.html"><img style="object-position: 60% 0%;" src="images/Life/1.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
        <div class="col"><a href=""><img src="images/Life/3.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
        <div class="col"><a href=""><img src="images/Lakers/L1000857.JPG" alt=""></a></div>
        <div class="col"><a href=""><img src="images/Lakers/L1000883.JPG" alt=""></a></div>
        <div class="col"><a href=""><img src="images/Others/1.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
        <div class="col"><a href=""><img src="images/Others/2.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
        <div class="col"><a href=""><img style="object-position: 60% 0%;" src="images/About/About me.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
    </div>
```

and my CSS:

```
.container-fluid{
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0  !important;
}
img{
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0  !important;
    height: 350px;
    width: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 60% 30%;

}
```

Comment: try applying 0 margin and padding on body element and inspect by dev tools from where this margin or padding is coming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`col` class by default has `padding-left: 15px` and `padding-right: 15px`. It can be removed by applying `p-0` Bootstrap class:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="col p-0"><a href="about.html"><img style="object-position: 60% 0%;" src="images/Life/1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col p-0"><a href=""><img src="images/Life/3.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="col p-0"><a href=""><img src="images/Lakers/L1000857.JPG" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="col p-0"><a href=""><img src="images/Lakers/L1000883.JPG" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="col p-0"><a href=""><img src="images/Others/1.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="col p-0"><a href=""><img src="images/Others/2.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
    <div class="col p-0"><a href=""><img style="object-position: 60% 0%;" src="images/About/About me.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[Read more about spacing here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)